# joda time hibernate to DB2 DATE

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, jodatime

I tried without succes to make a custom type mapping between DateTime joda and DATE db2.
Which annotations should we use in the case of using joda time hibernate library instead of custom type mapping  ? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just map plain java dates and convert to / from joda dates when you read / write the values?

Comment: +1: A perfectly reasonable approach.  Though I do use the library as noted in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open-source library supporting this on sourceforge](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html).  Now that I reread your question, you're likely already using it.

This includes a UserType so that you can map Joda DateTime fields with

```
   @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my project on Sourceforge (Usertype) which supports Joda Time and the JSR 310 drafts. Unlike the Joda Time Contrib library this works with Hibernate 3.6 and it should be very straightforward to use if you are familiar with Joda Time Contrib's Hibernate usertypes.

See http://usertype.sourceforge.net/